# P, NP and polynomial time reduction?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

If $P = NP$ would this imply that polynomial time reduction from an $NP$- to a $P$-problem would be possible? And if $P\neq NP$ does it imply that a polynomial time reduction from an $NP$- to a $P$-problem would be impossible?

Comment: Have you read the definition of these notions you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $P \subseteq NP$, every problem in $P$ is also in $NP$. So in both cases there is an $NP$-problem that can be reduced to a $P$-problem. Simply choose a problem in $P$ as the $NP$-problem and the same problem as the $P$-problem.

If you replace $NP$-problem by $NP$-complete problem, both of your statements hold.